# Highest data table values from items in list

Tags: c#, list, linq, datatable

I have a data table which looks like this:

```
type | Value
----------
  a  |  5
  b  |  6
  c  |  10
  d  |  23
  e  |  8
```

And I have a list where certain types are stored, like this:

```
var list = new List<string>() {a, c, e}
```

I'm not very good with LINQ, but I'm looking for a statement which returns the highest value of the types that are in the list. Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int maxValue = list.Max(m => 
    dt.AsEnumerable()
      .First(r => r.Field<string>("type") == m)
      .Field<int>("value")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
int maxValue = list.Max(m => 
    dt.AsEnumerable()
      .First(r => r.Field<string>("type") == m)
      .Field<int>("value")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication186
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "a", 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "b", 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "c", 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "d", 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "e", 0 });

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"a",5});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"b",6});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"c",10});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"d",23});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"e",8});

            List<DataRow> max = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<int>("Value"))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("type"))
                .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```